# If a transition lasts n seconds is it possible to start it at a specified percentage of that time?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a rectangle that is animated using `.transition()` and it takes 5 seconds (`.duration(5000)`). I want to know if there is any way to specify a *percentage* under those 5 seconds, so the animation is executed from that percentage on.

For example, with a duration of 5 seconds, if I specify a value of `50%`, I would like the animation to start from  the values corresponding to 2.5 seconds (50% of 5). Is that possible?

This is my code:

```js
d3.select("#visualization").append('svg');
var vis = d3.select("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 614).style("border", "1px solid red");

var rectangle = vis.append("rect").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 70).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 50);

rectangle
  .transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .attr("x", 250)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: did you want to delay the animation start time, like start after 2.5s, and last for 5s. If so, you can use `.delay(2500)` for postponing the animation.

Comment: @soundquiet no, I want the animation to continue from a point, not to take time to start

Comment: start from time 0 but only can be viewed from 2.5s? Not really understand what "to continue from 2.5 seconds" means

Comment: @soundquiet if my animation lasts 5 seconds and when finished it moves to the end 250 in `x`. Right? I want to somehow put a number that will define what percentage of that animation should continue. if I put 50 the animation must continue from 50%, that is, from 125 (50% of 250) to its final value which is 250 (this for `x`). now if you understand me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a **linear easing**, just change the duration and pass your own `ease` function, which can be as simple as:

```
const percentage = 0.5;//here, a value between 0 and 1

selection.transition()
    .duration(5000 * (1 - percentage))
    .ease(t => percentage + t * (1 - percentage))
    //etc...
```

If you have another easing, pass the modified `t` value to it. For instance, using `d3.easeCubic`:

```
.ease(t => d3.easeCubic(percentage + t * (1 - percentage)))
```

The logic here is simple: as the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) explains, *"for each frame that a transition is active, it invokes its tweens with an eased t-value ranging from 0 to 1"*. Therefore, our function just makes the transition starting at the eased value of `percentage` and the `t` value, going from 0 to 1, is used to indicate the fraction of the amount remaining (`1 - percentage`) that must be added. When `t = 1` the whole expression `percentage + t * (1 - percentage)` equals 1.

Here are the demos. First, your regular transition:

```js
const vis = d3.select("body").append('svg').attr("width", 800).attr("height", 614).style("border", "1px solid red");

var rectangle = vis.append("rect").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 70).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 50);

rectangle
  .transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .attr("x", 250)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now using `percentage = 0.5`, everything (positions, opacity etc...) starts at 50% of your original transition:

```js
const vis = d3.select("body").append('svg').attr("width", 800).attr("height", 614).style("border", "1px solid red");

var rectangle = vis.append("rect").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 70).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 50);

const percentage = 0.5;

rectangle
  .transition()
  .duration(5000 * (1 - percentage))
  .ease(t => d3.easeCubic(percentage + t * (1 - percentage)))
  .attr("x", 250)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, with `percentage = 0.8`. Because this is a cubic easing, the opacity/movement are almost ending:

```js
const vis = d3.select("body").append('svg').attr("width", 800).attr("height", 614).style("border", "1px solid red");

var rectangle = vis.append("rect").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 70).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 50);

const percentage = 0.8;

rectangle
  .transition()
  .duration(5000 * (1 - percentage))
  .ease(t => d3.easeCubic(percentage + t * (1 - percentage)))
  .attr("x", 250)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

PS: not related, use `style` instead of `attr` for setting styles. You'll see that, in your specific case, it makes a huge difference.